# Setting/understanding how #define is used in a header file (setting from cmakelist)

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I am writing a simple logging library and I am trying to set a compile time definition on the logging level. If I put the `#define LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL` in the header file it is not being set at compile time, however if the `#define LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL` is in the c file it does work.

Here are snippets of the relevant sections

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
// Trying to set LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL to ERROR
add_definitions(-DLOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL=ERROR)
# I have also tried
add_compile_definitions(LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL=ERROR)
```

In `log.h`

```
// I define in this file the following (technically they are enums with values set)
// DEBUG = 0, INFO = 1, WARN = 2, ERROR = 3

// By default resort to INFO if not found
#ifndef LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL
#define LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL INFO
#endif

// In log.h I am trying to do this, where before even going to
// the log function (log_log) the level is checked against the compile level
// So since I (in theory) set LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL to ERROR, any INFO levels
// are not logged since INFO (value of 1) is below LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL which is 
// set to ERROR (value of 3)
// Ideally/in theory the compiler will compile out any messages not used by doing this....
#define LOG(level, __FILENAME__, __LINE__, ...) \
  if (level < LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL);\
  else log_log(level, __FILENAME__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)

// The reason for having LOG and LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL in the header is cause I provide
// some logging macros like:
#define LOG_ERROR(...) LOG(ERROR, __FILENAME__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

```
// In some c/cpp file, this should not work since log level is set to
// ERROR but it does (because the default value of LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL is
// info.
LOG_INFO("My info message);
```

No matter what I have tried in the CMakeLists.txt I cannot get it to work. Now when I move

```
#ifndef LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL
#define LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL INFO
#endif
```

To a c/cpp file it does work (gets set to ERROR).

1. Why?
2. What is happening?
3. How can I set it for the header file?

The reason I am trying to set/define it in the header file is for `#define LOG` method.

Comment: Please post a complete [MCVE]. `LOG_INFO` Is nowhere defined.

Comment: You can't specify compile definitions passed to a compiler for a header file (at least not with regular compilation) since you pass C/CPP source files so these compile definitions need to be available each time you compile a file that includes `log.h`, even if it does so indirectly. Not sure what goes wrong in your case since there's neither a source file demonstrating the behavior not a `CMakeLists.txt` file used to create the build system shown in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What could be wrong

Although the example is not proper for reproduction, and the definition of the `INFO` is not provided, based on the explanation that the token is defined as `enum`, I have strong filling that this is the problem. The `enum` types do not mix well with the macros, since `enum` are constructed in the compile time and macros are evaluated in the pre-processing time (before the compile starts).

#### Working example

The approach should work from both .c and .h files. I have made a minimal example and it worked fine:

**test.h**

```
#define DEBUG = 0
#define INFO = 1
#define WARN = 2
#define ERROR = 3

#ifndef LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL
#define LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL INFO
#endif
```

**test.c**

```
#include "test.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv) {
    printf("%i\n",LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL);
#if LOG_COMPILE_MIN_LEVEL == 1
    printf("Log set to INFO\n");`
#endif
}
```

After passing the file trough the pre-processor stage only `gcc -E test.c`, I get the following output:

```
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "test.h" 1
# 2 "test.c" 2

int main(int argc, char *argv) {
 printf("%i\n",1);

 printf("Log set to INFO\n");`

}
```

as you can see, the pre-processor had recognized the macros and had performed the replacement properly.

#### Troubleshooting

The `C/C++` compilers are allowing you to produce the pre-processed file only. The role of the pre-processed file is to help in the debugging of problems like this, so create a minimal example (like my case) and pass it only trough the pre-processor. For GCC, the `-E` is the instruction telling the complier to produce and present on `stdout` the pre-processed version of the file.